# Is it possible to asynchronously collect items from a generator into an array?

Tags: javascript, promise, generator, ecmascript-6, bluebird

I'm playing around with writing a web service using Node.js/Express which generates some objects based on templates and then returns the generated data.  I'm using Bluebird promises to manage all the async logic.  After stripping out all the unimportant stuff, my code looks something like this[1].

My problem is the core logic can block for several seconds if the requested number of output elements is large.  Since I've been playing with ES6 for this project, my first thought was to factor out the element creation into a generator[2].  However, the only way I can find to get all the results from this generator is `Array.from`, which doesn't help with the blocking.

I've played around with `.map`, `.all`, `.coroutine`, and a couple of other things, in an attempt to asynchronously collect the results from the generator, but I haven't had any luck.  Is there any nice way to do this with Bluebird? (Or perhaps a better way of doing it altogether?)

Native ES6 Promise.all can take an iterator and give back an array of values, but [V8 doesn't support this yet](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=441175).  Also, in my experimentation with polyfills/Firefox, it seems to be synchronous.

This is not-too-common operation, so I don't care much about absolute performance.  I just want to avoid blocking the event queue, and I would prefer a nice, easy to read and maintain solution.

[1]:

```
let Bluebird = require('bluebird');

let templates = ...; // logic to load data templates 

function createRandomElementFromRandomTemplate(templates) {
    let el;
    // synchronous work that can take a couple of milliseconds...
    return el;
};

api.createRandomElements = function(req, res) {
    let numEls = req.params.numEls;

    Bluebird.resolve(templates)
    .then(templates => {
        let elements = [];
        // numEls could potentially be several thousand
        for(let i = 0; i < numEls; ++i) {
            elements.push(createRandomElementFromRandomTemplate(templates));
        }
        return elements;
    })
    .then(elements => {
        res.json(elements);
    })
    .error(err => {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    });
}
```

[2]:

```
function* generateRandomElementsFromRandomTemplate(templates, numEls) {
    for(let i = 0; i < numEls; ++i) {
        let el;
        // synchronous work that can take a couple of milliseconds...
        yield el;
    }
}

api.createRandomElements = function(req, res) {
    let numEls = req.params.numEls;

    Bluebird.resolve(templates)
    .then(templates => {
        // this still blocks
        return Array.from(generateRandomElementsFromRandomTemplate(templates, numEls));
    })
    .then(elements => {
        res.json(elements);
    })
    .error(err => {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: We were considering adding the ability to pass an iterator to Promise.all but figured no one would use it - please open an issue on the bluebird GitHub - this is definitely something to consider.

Comment: As a workaround - Promise.map takes a second parameter of configuration, you can pass it a concurrency value which might fix your problem: See [the official API docs](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#option-concurrency)

Comment: Even if promise.all supported iterable, it would simply just turn it into array and use the array...

Comment: @Esailija yes, in general since map does not have an order guarantee supporting iterables in map and all is not very interesting (but worth reconsidering if a real need arises) - supporting them with `.each` might be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a halfway-decent solution I found after looking more closely at Bluebird's `.map()` as Benjamin suggested.  I still have the feeling I'm missing something, though.

The main reason I started with Bluebird was because of Mongoose, so I left a bit of that in for a more realistic sample.

```
let Bluebird = require('bluebird');
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
Bluebird.promisifyAll(mongoose);

const Template = mongoose.models.Template,
      UserPref = mongoose.models.UserPref;

// just a normal function that generates one element with a random choice of template
function createRandomElementFromRandomTemplate(templates, userPrefs) {
    let el;
    // synchronous work that can take a couple of milliseconds...
    return el;
}

api.generate = function(req, res) {
    let userId = req.params.userId;
    let numRecord = req.params.numRecords
    let data;
    Bluebird.props({
        userprefs: UserPref.findOneAsync({userId: userId}), 
        templates: Template.findAsync({})
    })
    .then(_data => {
        data = _data;
        // use a sparse array to convince .map() to loop the desired number of times
        return Array(numRecords);
    })
    .map(() => {
        // ignore the parameter map passes in - we're using the exact same data in each iteration
        // generate one item each time and let Bluebird collect them into an array
        // I think this could work just as easily with a coroutine
        return Bluebird.delay(createRandomElementFromRandomTemplate(data.templates, data.userprefs), 0);
    }, {concurrency: 5})
    .then(generated => {
        return Generated.createAsync(generated);
    })
    .then(results => {
        res.json(results);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500);
    });
};
```

Comment: Why not just return `new Array(numRecords)`? Shorter on two lines

Comment: Those "let"s - are you using 6to5 by any chance? (or just io?)

Comment: Well, I must admit. @BenjaminGruenbaum solution looks much, much, much prettier then mine.

Comment: @alexpods: D'oh, I forgot about that.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Yes, 6to5.  It seems to work fairly well so far.

Comment: Ok, I'm removing my poor suggestion. @BenjaminGruenbaum, it's was nice to dispute with you

Comment: @alexpods any time, please do participate in the tag :) mmebane - works nice for me too :) Letting you know you can use async functions and other goodies for a lot of these things, 6to5 even has a bluebirdCoroutine flag.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I looked into it a little bit, but it's going to take me a while to fully wrap my head around async functions. :)